# Can't remove a listener from an Electron IPC added from React Component

Tags: reactjs, electron

I have a simple React component that registers a new listener in IPC on mounting and should remove the listener when unmounting. The problem is that my listener reference for some reason doesn't match the reference that was used to register it and I have no idea why.

#### React component simplified code

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useAppDispatch } from '../../redux/storeHooks';
import { setAuthToken } from './state/authSlice';

import { LocationAuthState } from '../common/RequireAuth/types';

export default () => {
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const navigatedFrom = useNavigatedFrom();

    useEffect(() => {
        const userLoggedInHandler = (_: Electron.IpcRendererEvent, loginToken: string) => {
            dispatch(setAuthToken({ token: loginToken }));
            navigate(navigatedFrom, { replace: true });
        };

        const ref1 = userLoggedInHandler;

        window.ipc.startLoginListenerHttpServer();
        window.ipc.userLoggedIn(userLoggedInHandler);

        return () => {
            const theSame = ref1 === userLoggedInHandler;
            console.log(theSame); // this logs true

            window.ipc.stopLoginListenerHttpServer();
            window.ipc.removeUserLoggedInListener(userLoggedInHandler);
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            {`Waiting for login result...`}
        </div>
    );
};

function useNavigatedFrom() {
    const location = useLocation();
    const locationState = location.state as LocationAuthState;
    return locationState?.from?.pathname || `/`;
}
```

#### preload.js

```js
import { contextBridge, ipcRenderer, IpcRendererEvent } from 'electron';
import IpcEvent from '../ipcEvent';

let originalHandlerReference: any;

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(`ipc`, {
    startLoginListenerHttpServer: () => ipcRenderer.send(IpcEvent.StartLoginListenerHttpServer),
    stopLoginListenerHttpServer: () => ipcRenderer.send(IpcEvent.StopLoginListenerHttpServer),

    userLoggedIn: (handler: (event: IpcRendererEvent, loginToken: string) => void) => {
        originalHandlerReference = handler;
        ipcRenderer.on(IpcEvent.UserLoggedIn, handler);
    },

    removeUserLoggedInListener: (handler: (event: IpcRendererEvent, loginToken: string) => void) => {
        const countBefore = ipcRenderer.listenerCount(IpcEvent.UserLoggedIn); // 1

        const theSame = originalHandlerReference === handler; // false

        const theSameAsOriginal = originalHandlerReference === ipcRenderer.listeners(IpcEvent.UserLoggedIn)[0]; // true
        const theSameAsCurrentHandler = handler === ipcRenderer.listeners(IpcEvent.UserLoggedIn)[0]; // false

        ipcRenderer.off(IpcEvent.UserLoggedIn, handler);

        const countAfter = ipcRenderer.listenerCount(IpcEvent.UserLoggedIn); // 1
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at the [Electron documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/context-bridge#parameter--error--return-type-support) on `contextBridge`, we can see that the communication between the "normal" renderer process and the isolated part executing the preload script is *copied* both ways. This means that no two objects passed between the renderer and the preload context (and vice versa) will be *exactly* the same.

Thus, you cannot use `===` to check if the two functions passed to your preload script are equal. I would suggest generating an ID for each registered listener, passing it to the calling code and storing it in a map alongside the actual function. That way, the component could call your "unmount" function providing the ID it was given when registering its listener, the preload script would lookup the handler function for the given ID and remove it from IPC channels.

Comment: Thank you. After some more digging I found this answer, for a bit different problem, but the solution is still applicable to my issue: https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template/issues/43#issuecomment-772303787
In short: return listenerRemover function from the method that adds listeners.

Comment: Mind that this will still copy functions across contexts, which may not be the most performant thing to do if you have lots of IPC communication, but yes, it is more or less functionally equivalent.